# Error dropping WCF Activity in Workflow ("Cannot create an instance of "...)

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation

I need to create a Workflow Service in Visual Studio 2013, so I created a WCF Workflow Service Application. Most activities come from WCF web services published in a another project, so I added a service reference to my web services project.

The activities from the web services appears in the Toolbox, but when I try to drag and drop one of them to the Workflow I always got this error message : "Cannot create an instance of 'service_name'. 'Resource not found'"

I created a few workflows in the past and never had this problem before.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you specify the endpoint?

Comment: Yes, it was automatically created in the web.config when I created the service reference.

Comment: @moikey the generated code has a xaml file which open as a workflow designer. In that designer screen there is a sequence workflow with a Send activity. That activity shows an error of end point not being specified. However there is another generated file: endpointConfigurationNameResolver.svcinfo.  I don't really know what we are supposed to do to consume these generated activities. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check your build targets!

Had the same problem and found that the project I was adding from had build target "ANY" while the project I was adding to had "x86"!

After setting both projects to the same build target it worked...

Answer (score 0):

You have probably already resolved the issue, but I am writing this for people that may run into the same problem.

Once the service references are added to the project, before drag and dropping the activities in the workflow, you need to build the project in which you have added the activities, once you have done that, you should be able to add the activities to the workflow.